# How do I get values from a certain column which are greater than values from another?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a df with temperature data for 2 different periods 2015 and other. I would like to create a 3rd column which returns value for  2015 if greater than other but 0 if less.

[image: joined df]

I tried this :

```
joined =x.join(y, lsuffix='2015', rsuffix='other')

joined.Data_Value2015.apply(lambda x: x if x > joined.Data_Valueother else 0 )
```

Comment: Use `joined['new'] = np.where(joined.Data_Value2015 > joined.Data_Valueother, joined.Data_Value2015, 0)`

Comment: It works. Thanks.